# Data Pager jumping to first page

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, datapager

I have a data grid which uses a Data Pager to split the data grid up into pages.

I have a button which opens a child window (for editing the data in the grid)

The problem occurs if i navigate to any other page other than 1 - then click the button to edit (which opens the child window), upon closing the child window my Data Pager jumps back to page 1. I would like it to retain the same page that i was viewing after the child window is closed.

**Data Pager:**

```
 <sdk:DataPager Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="pager"  DisplayMode="FirstLastPreviousNextNumeric" PageSize="30" NumericButtonCount="4" Source="{Binding Path=ItemsSource,ElementName=MyGrid}" />
```

**Child window closing method:**

```
 Private Sub BtnCancelClick(sender As System.Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
        Close()
 End Sub
```

As you can see, I'm not doing anything other than the default `Close()` method when i click my cancel button. Is this a built in problem, is there a way to override this?

Comment: Sounds like your datagrid is getting reloaded after the edit. Try saving the current page and setting it back after the edit is done. While you're not reloading it, depending on how you are loading the data, your data provider might be.

Comment: @Steve I just put a break point everywhere that i am setting my Grids ItemsSource - none got hit

Comment: What is your ItemSource? Is it an ObservableCollection, PagedView or something like that? Where are those being populated? You only need to set the ItemSource once when you use stuff like this.

Comment: @Steve It's a pagedCollectionView. Yep, I'm setting the itemsSource once in a build method. However I'm also setting it in a search method - which handles textchanged of a search box, but this shouldn't make any difference as the search box is not used to reproduce this bug.

Comment: But, the PagedCollectionView wraps an ObservableCollection and when a record is added/removed from it, your Pages reset and your view is recreated. Just a guess. Point is, you need to do more searching than just the ItemSource. You need to look at where you modify your collections that FEED the ItemSource.

Comment: @Steve Ah okay i understand. Ill dig a bit deeper into it - Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to setting the page on a DataPager?

Comment: That wasn't the problem I had but I'm pretty sure it's possible